# How to update displayed data in the view, without refreshing the page?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Usecase where the user can favorite an item. The code below shows how I am retrieving data from the database to display in the view.

Favorite service

```
   async getfavoriteList(): Promise<firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot> {
    const user: firebase.User = await this.authService.getUser();
    if (user) 
          {
    this.FavoriteListRef = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`userFavorites`);
    return this.FavoriteListRef.where('uid', '==', user.uid).get();
              }
           } 
       }
```

Favorite.ts

```
ngOnInit() {    this.favoriteService.getfavoriteList().then(favoriteListSnapshot => {
      this.favoriteList = [];
      favoriteListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.favoriteList.push({
          id: snap.id,
          favoriteList: snap.data().favourite
        });
        console.log(snap.data().favourite)
        return false;
      });
    }); 

  }
```

The problem I have is that when the user favorites an item, and goes to the favorites page to see the favorited item, the view does not update unless the page is refreshed. This isn't ideal user experience. How can I update the view without refreshing the page. I have tried placing the code in the constructor function as well as ngOnInit(), but the page does not update.

Comment: You return a Promise, it resolves and is done. [Try docs and ask if needed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

Comment: I'm hoping this issue has been resolved since it's been over a month. However, in the event that it isn't, although my background stems from a MERN stack, and most of my front end experience stems from React, I did encounter this kind of problem in the past. For me, it was a matter of executing the updating function in the proper lifecycle hook. In my case, it was `componentDidUpdate()` where I would update the component's `state` object whenever there has been changes. I would suggest experimenting with the different lifecycles in Angular such as `ngOnChanges`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use an `Observable` over a `promise`. This would help you to fetch data without a reload.

[*Refer official documentation*](https://angular.io/guide/observables).